# Performance: Rails 3.2.8 development log displays lots of CACHE lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In development in Rails 3.2.8 I get a lot of lines from CACHE like this.

```
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" IN (1, 7)
```

I know that rails is caching the queries to improve performance. An all the caching lines are done in 0,0 ms. So, it might not be a problem.

**Question**

Should I try to improve my code/design to get rid of so much caching I can? Would it improve performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caching typically improves, not hurts, application performance. By default, within a single request, exact same query will only run once and the rest of the times results will be cached. This is what you are observing with CACHE log entries.

What it means, however, is that your application tries to execute exact same query multiple times. So yes, I would suggest that you look into what parts of your model are getting requested repeatedly and maybe hold on to materialized `.all` results and pass them around as parameters instead of querying your models.

More precise answer of course depends on your specific scenario, but your instinct is correct - a lot of cache hits hint towards a design that could probably be improved a bit.

Once more thing to note: if you want to ensure that your query executes non-cached, wrap it in the uncached method like so:

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do
    # your code here   
  end
```